# How to use replaceFirst to Replace {....}

Tags: java, string, replace

I am having a string which contains `xyaahhfhajfahj{adhadh}fsfhgs{sfsf}`.

Now I want to replace `{string}` with a space.
I want to replace the curly brackets and the string in it with null.

I want to use `replaceFirst` for it but I don't know the regex for doing it.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you want with an example output.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class TestCls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "xyaahhfhajfahj{adhadh}fsfhgs{sfsf}";
        String str1 = str.replaceAll("\\{[a-zA-z0-9]*\\}", " ");// to replace string within "{" & "}" with " ".
        String str2 = str.replaceFirst("\\{[a-zA-z0-9]*\\}", " ");// to replace first string within "{" & "}" with " ".
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying that you want to find the first occurrence of anything inside of `{` and `}`, then replace it including the brackets with nothing, here's an example that will do that:

```
String input = "xyaahhfhajfahj{adhadh}fsfhgs{sfsf}";
String output = input.replaceFirst("\\{.*?\\}", "");
System.out.println(output ); // output will be "xyaahhfhajfahjfsfhgs{sfsf}"
```

Comment: Using a negative character class is more efficient than a lazy quantifier -- for example `"\\{[^}]*\\}"`.