# Replacing contents of a String using replaceFirst()

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a file with below contents:

```
Test:Line1@line.com
Goal:[[goal]]
Email:[[email]]
Further Text
```

Below is code to get the file contents into a StringBuffer and get the value into the String `output`.

```
Path signature = Paths.get("signature.txt");
StringBuffer sigBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
 reader = Files.newBufferedReader(signature);
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   sigBuffer.append(line);
   sigBuffer.append("\n");
 }
 String output = sigBuffer.toString();
} catch...finally...
```

I want to replace the `[[goal]]` with `Goal A`
AND `[[email]]` with `email@mail.com`

I tried this:

```
String regExp = "\\[\\[[a-z_]*\\]\\]";
output.replaceFirst(regExp, "Goal A");
output.replaceFirst(regExp, "email@mail.com");
```

But my output is still:

```
Test:Line1@line.com
Goal:[[goal]]
Email:[[email]]
Further Text
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658794/how-to-use-replacefirst-to-replace?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String is immutable. You need to assign the result of the `replaceFirst` call back to the variable.

```
output = output.replaceFirst(....)
```

Comment: Maybe downvoted because there are dupes, which themselves have dupes ad nauseum, for this problem